# Syntax highlighting via Prism in Glorious Demo

Tags: javascript, prismjs

So I found out about 'Glorious Demo' today, and I'm testing out a demo of it. After getting Glorious Demo to work initially, I tried adding **syntax highlighting via Prism**. However, when I add the line `const highlightedCode = Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages.clike, 'clike');` my app breaks. What gives?

I am very much a beginner, so I apologize if I'm making some basic mistake and not realizing it.

```html
<!-- A 'Glorious Demo' application for showcasing the example from 'Get Started with C Programming' -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glorious/demo/dist/gdemo.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs/components/prism-clike.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glorious/demo/dist/gdemo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>

<script>
const gdemo = new GDemo('#container');

const code = '#include <stdio.h>\n#include <conio.h>\nvoid main()\n{\nprintf("Hello World!");\ngetch();\n}'

const highlightedCode = Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages.clike, 'clike');

gdemo
  .openApp('editor', {
    minHeight: '400px',
    windowTitle: 'hello_world.c'
  })
  .write(code, {
    onCompleteDelay: 2000
  })
  .openApp('terminal', {
    minHeight: '400px',
    promptString: '$'
  })
  .command('gcc ./hello_world.c')
  .respond('Hello World!')
  .command('')
  .end();
</script>
</html>
```